# how do I delete the first 4 numbers of an 8 number in a cell for each cell in a column?

Tags: vba

I am new to VBA and for work, I need to fix a column that contains order numbers and invoice numbers altogether in the same cell. it is supposed to only have order numbersin one cell but the last intern screwed it up and put both invoice number and order number in the same cell. I would do it by hand but the column is huge.

Comment: Do you mean the first 4 characters? If yes and all cell value has 8 digits, you can use a simple code using `Cell().Value = Right(Cell().value, 4)`. What column would you like to process? But, it is a simple task and you could find something only searching on Google, I think...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub testReplaceFourDigits()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, colLetter As String, i As Long
 
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  colLetter = "A" 'change here your column letter
  lastR = sh.range(colLetter & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  For i = 2 To lastR
     sh.range(colLetter & i).Value = Right(sh.range(colLetter & i).Value, 4)
  Next i
End Sub
```

It works as expected for a total of 8 digits value. If the total number of digits is variable, the code can be easily adapted...

If you really need to delete the first 'numbers' and alpha numeric characters also exist, it is a little more complicated but possible.